# keep dropdown menu open after user navigate to other page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this side menu, each item with sub-items, that when clicked go to another page.

When I press the sub-item of master and I load another page, the menu collapses like in the first photo. Is there any way to keep the menu open when navigating to other pages. This below is my HTML code. I've been stuck for an hour with this problem. I've tried options from similar questions here but no luck. I'm fairly new to front-end development, so any help would be appreciated.

[image: photo 1]
[image: photo 2]

```js
(function($) {
    "use strict";
    // Add active state to sidbar nav links
    var path = window.location.href; // because the 'href' property of the DOM element is the absolute path
    $("#layoutSidenav_nav .sb-sidenav a.nav-link").each(function() {
      if (this.href === path) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
      }
      var $dropdownmenu = $(this);
      $(this).find('a').each(function() {
        console.log($dropdownmenu); // this is your dropdown menu which you want to display
        console.log($($dropdownmenu).parents('li')); // this is the parent list item of the dropdown menu. Add collapse class or whatever that collapses its child list
      });

      // Toggle the side navigation
      $("#sidebarToggle").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("body").toggleClass("sb-sidenav-toggled");
      });
    })(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Pusat-data" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Pusat-data">

  <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-list"></i></div>
  Pusat Data
  <div class="sb-sidenav-collapse-arrow"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></div>
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="Pusat-data" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#sidenavAccordion">
  <!-- sidenavaccordion tidak usah di ganti ID -->
  <nav class="sb-sidenav-menu-nested nav">
    <a class="nav-link" href="\PT APU SI\menu_APUBUSSINESS 2.0\Master Data\User_Master.html">Users</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="\PT APU SI\menu_APUBUSSINESS 2.0\Master Data\Gudang_Master.html">Gudang</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="\PT APU SI\menu_APUBUSSINESS 2.0\Master Data\Supplier_Master.html">Supplier</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="\PT APU SI\menu_APUBUSSINESS 2.0\Master Data\Barang_Master.html">Barang</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="\PT APU SI\menu_APUBUSSINESS 2.0\Master Data\Customer_Master.html">Customer</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="\PT APU SI\menu_APUBUSSINESS 2.0\Master Data\Payment_Master.html">Pembayaran</a>

  </nav>
</div>
<!-- END OF THE LINE -->
```

Comment: Add class "sb-sidenav-toggled" to your body tag on other pages

Answer (score 0):

The only way for that menu to stay open when you load another page is to pass information to the new page that will instruct the menu to change to a particular state.

There are several ways this can be done.

**first option**

This can be done fairly easily with a SPA(single page application) like React.js, because in a SPA when you "load another page" what's really happening is javascript is managing a child element into the HTML, so a page refresh isn't actually happening and the state of the menu remains the same when the "pages" are swapped in and out of the primary section of the html.

**second option**

Since you're using an href and making the page load, I'm assuming you're using some server-side rendering framework like ROR or laravel.

You can pass data to a new page load. This is typically done with something called a page parameter and it looks like this ([www.somelink.com/dashboard?menu_state=892374562384659](http://www.somelink.com/dashboard?menu_state=892374562384659))

Where the integer can be parsed into some state of the menu, and the integer is generated from a function that rescues the current state of the menu before the new page request is sent.

**third option**

Modern browsers provide a wide variety of tools to tackle things like this. Something else you can do is use the browser as a bridge to hold page state information or menu state information. Most modern browsers have a variety of ways to store information in the browser regardless of what page is loaded. Chrome has something call localStorage and most other browsers have something similar. There is also sessions data(typically stored on the server) and cookies(typically stored in the browser)

You could pass information containing the state of the menu to one of the bridges I mentioned, and then reference it on each page load to rescue the menu state. The only caution here is browser stored information is completely not secure so you must make sure anything in localStorage is unimportant.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="nav-link collapsed dropdown-link" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Pusat-data" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Pusat-data">



 $("#layoutSidenav_nav .sb-sidenav a.dropdown-link").each(function() {

.nav-link::active{
  color:white;
 }
```